# Falha ao adicionar a referência "System.runtime" no asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, nuget

Estou tentando instalar a ultima "stable version" do Mysql.Data pelo NuGet package manager. A versão em questão é a 6.10.5.

Ao tentar instalar, a mensagem abaixo é apresentada:
`Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache`

Procurei pela internet por soluções, mas nenhuma conseguiu me ajudar. Tentei adicionar uma versão inferior e funcionou bem. Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Pode ser que o tipo do seu projeto não seja compatível com essa dll.

Comment: Como assim @MayconF.Castro? Eu estou fazendo um asp.net web API. Acredita ser a compatibilidade? Essa é minha primeira API em asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido com o downgrade de versão. Vou aguardar um próximo update do pacote e testar.